# How to calculate the zero input response of the current through an inductor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: TA Solution]

[image: My solution]

The question is find the current through the inductor when the i<sub>L</sub>(0<sup>-</sup>)=.5A.
The top picture is the posted solution. My solution is on the bottom. They are not the same and I realize that I should not have a u(t) term in my solution as we are only dealing with the initial condition of the capacitor.

My question is why do they have the admittance of the capacitor over the total admittance instead of admittance of the inductor of total admittance?

Also, are our schematics fundamentally different?

I know there are other ways to solve this but this is the only way we have learned so far so I will be expected to do it this way on my midterm this Wednesday.

Comment: Please do what you need to to make the top image legible.  Decrease contrast a bit or strengthen the original lines and re photograph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the posted solution is true. It is actually the inductor's admittance over the total admittance, because this is what you get if you try to solve it by voltage insead of current (which is an alternative solution). But, it is more practical to solve a parallel circuit with current and a series circuit with voltage.